# Multiple Azure applications with version independent common microservices on the same cluster

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-deployment

We have multiple Azure applications that use shared microservices (Indexing, Indexing Management, etc) via git submodules.  We deployed the first application without any problems, but when attempting to deploy the second application, the microservices where not created in the application.

As these microservices are submodules, they share the same ServiceManifest and have identical names and version numbers.  Currently both are at the same commit, but in the future they can be independent of each other.

Is the shared name causing our deployment issues despite being in separate applications?

Comment: Deployed to what? Azure Web Apps? Containers? Service Fabric? AKS?

Comment: It is a Service Fabric deployment

Comment: There should be some kind of deployment logs available to you. That would be the first place to start. In general, you cannot deploy the same version of the same application more than once to a cluster, but I'm not sure if that's the issue here.

Comment: Please share your application manifest to make it easier to help you!

Comment: I just updated the ServiceManifest names to be unique between the applications and still not deploying.
Does the application update replace all existing services before adding the new services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The existing services depend on the new service, but the new service is not deployed till the existing services are successfully upgraded which they never are as the existing services are waiting on the new (undeployed) service.

[Documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade)